# Flutter requires sudo when in my own user folder

Tags: linux, macos, flutter, terminal

I am setting up Flutter, but am only able to run flutter commands by adding sudo before the command.

The error I get is:

```
shlock: 
    open(/Users/drandomuom/dev/flutter/bin/cache/shlock97760): 
    Permission denied
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this, as I'm working in my own home folder.

Any advice would be great. Thanks.

I have tried running in zsh and bash, I have checked the folder permissions and have read & write

Comment: Please check also the permissions of all parent directories.

Comment: Each file above is read & write (drwxr-xr-x) but the group is staff, not users. Would this make a difference?
`drwxr-xr-x   13 drandomuom  staff    416  9 Jul 17:09 dev`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at jww's edit, I started looking into user permissions in linux. I found that the folder for flutter was owned by root, rather than my actual profile. To test this, I created a new profile on the laptop, and reinstalled flutter. This time, the folder was owned by my user, and I am able to run the flutter commands normally. I must have installed it with the sudo command originally.